# Generic function type is not applied to the returned object members

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

I'm defining a function which returns an object which members are functions with the same payload. Payload type is defined through [generic](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/), which extends object. However, flow complains that generic type is different then passed:

```
export const getObj = <T: {}>(url: string) => ({
  create: (entity: T) => console.log(url, entity),
  ...
});

const url = '/some-path';

type TEntity = {
  some: string,
};

const entity: TEntity = {
  some: 'value',
};

const instance = getObj<TEntity>(url);

instance.create(entity);
```

Flow complains:

> ^ Cannot call `instance.create` with `entity` bound to `entity` because `TEntity` [2](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiCmAPADrATgF1AMawB2AzvgOYq4DyARgFagC8oAPACoB8AFAK7ZoALlDlsAS2IUAlCy6geAb0ShC2FAENcKETxTFc43AE8RHWc3lEysaCgB0cCv0EAaUPsMnprxAF9pAG5ka3JQAWgWUAByYFJYAFsUAFoMLQALaODEEwwUUA4AUQMjYyjlVXikkTFJCl8-bND8T1KzYq8y1grRRJ0YgDcNaD4UaIamkjDJcg1iAnzWKlpGTg7S3gig5BncOYX7AnUtFD0S70CgA) is incompatible with `T` [2](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiCmAPADrATgF1AMawB2AzvgOYq4DyARgFagC8oAPACoB8AFAK7ZoALlDlsAS2IUAlCy6geAb0ShC2FAENcKETxTFc43AE8RHWc3lEysaCgB0cCv0EAaUPsMnprxAF9pAG5ka3JQAWgWUAByYFJYAFsUAFoMLQALaODEEwwUUA4AUQMjYyjlVXikkTFJCl8-bND8T1KzYq8y1grRRJ0YgDcNaD4UaIamkjDJcg1iAnzWKlpGTg7S3gig5BncOYX7AnUtFD0S70CgA).

[Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiCmAPADrATgF1AMawB2AzvgOYq4DyARgFagC8oAPACoB8AFAK7ZoALlDlsAS2IUAlCy6geAb0ShC2FAENcKETxTFc43AE8RHWc3lEysaCgB0cCv0EAaUPsMnprxAF9pAG5ka3JQAWgWUAByYFJYAFsUAFoMLQALaODEEwwUUA4AUQMjYyjlVXikkTFJCl8-bND8T1KzYq8y1grRRJ0YgDcNaD4UaIamkjDJcg1iAnzWKlpGTg7S3gig5BncOYX7AnUtFD0S70CgA).

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: So why have you not set create to be Tentity?  `create: (entity: TEntity)`

Comment: At first, b/c I need it the way `getObj<TOtherEntity>` and `getObj<TVeryOtherEntity>` (and a lot of other ways)  too. And second is b/c beside the `create`, there are other methods which need same type for correct definition. They way you suggested it'll be a very lot of copy-paste. @Keith

Comment: I don't have a complete answer yet but I got Flow to behave by declaring the return type of `getObj` with `T` instead of annotating with `T` inline. Here's the [Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQPICMBWAeAFQC5EBvRAOisQF8A+AChACcAbEgZymZjGQEoSpAD4AoRIgjNUAQyioSBRAF46iAG5wYAE1HCaZcYmlQWSclNnySqMLCgBPFWogIOcVqgqs4yJmwAaRFt7B35aAG5RGlFRRwAHVEQCAFE7GEcVMkR3AFsFHO5eZEjY1zAuYPTMiSzyPIKAcg4QxtLyyrA4KDTQusQZQZJGrFG2mijaqemZ2bn5xFEOqEReLhlIJOUUdGx8VOqHRkaAegaAWni5AAtG-ijRNagNiC9LOVQGEIywqKeXt7SD4MLo9Q73IA) for now, but I'm hoping to figure out a real answer soon.

Comment: @user11307804, yeah I feel that define returned type might be an acceptable workaround. Strange that flow can't calculate it himself though...

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, [be more explicit.](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AUQHYoCW6AYgIYDGKsATmgDwAqAfKALygAkASluQBMA8vmiMA3gB9EoUJVr8UWAFygAFEwCUHNgDdYRAQBpEkgL4sA3MiwAPDHRRzY+AM5OA5lhRCARgCsOUGYWNQBXWmhVd1oifA9NVQJiMioaehCddXEZOQVyJVU1LEISNFUtLMoXV1hoLAA6OA9wyKNQEpS0TRMzTWtEarcnCOgggHJgWoBbLABaDAKAC3GB9GxQJmSyoJzZGZVQGLiPXoGh9w7S9Art9F3cg9Vx3XJoMKxxs+QLpzj3cj4Sg4TheHwBZh3NChUb9ZD-FCA4ENeSKLDFa7dSxAA)

```
// @flow

type EntityFactory<T> = $ReadOnly<{|
  create: (T) => void,
|}>;

export const getObj = <T>(url: string): EntityFactory<T> => ({
  create: (entity: T) => console.log(url, entity),
});

const url = '/some-path';

type TEntity = {
  some: string,
};

const entity: TEntity = {
  some: 'value',
};

const instance = getObj<TEntity>(url);

instance.create(entity);
```

Comment: Please don't try to be cute with the links. If for some reason in the future that link no longer functioned, [this answer would not be helpful to anyone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/313880). Provide the relevant code directly in your answer as a code block.

Comment: This is something that frustrates me about the StackOverflow format. I'm a guy with the answer to the question, but also too busy to do a good job answering the question. If I leave a poorly formatted answer to the question, what's the worst that could happen? Will I get banned or something? What does SO do with users who want to help but don't want to put enough work in to make the answers actually good?